# Not compiling parts of the code in java(like #ifdef)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotations

I want to have the possibility NOT to compile parts of my JAVA code. Sometimes...

I miss the possibility of compiler directives I had in c++

```
#ifdef DEBUG
 println("debug messae);
#endif
```

In java we don't have this possibility.

I wondered if there is an external tool, some sort of a Java precompiler that might give me the flexibility to do this with java code.

Thank you,
Gilad

Comment: You can use loggers for that. What level is enables like error,debug etc can be specified by config files.

Comment: @AniketThakur I don't want this code to be incorporated in the byte code at all...

Answer (score 0):

`static final booleans` can be used to eliminate code inside `if statements` at compile time. for example

```
private static final boolean check= false;    

if (check) {
  // This is removed at compile time
}
```